# Как в codeception для определенной группы тестов использовать свой config?

Tags: php, test-automation, codeception

Добрый день.
Вопрос следующий есть множество acceptance тестов. 
и есть несколько тестов в acceptance/init которые по плану должны запускаться отдельно и производить первоначальную инициализацию нашего продукта. Вопрос в том как при выполнении тестов acceptance/init подгрузить свой файл конфигурации acceptance.suite.yml? и свой файл фикстур fixture.app.yml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это совсем отдельные тесты требующие отдельных настроек, то как Вам вариант создать новый Suite со своим конфигом? К примеру:
`codecept generate:suite init`
Далее настроить конфиг сюита и переместить туда все тесты из Init.